# Custom CSS to change style of dropdown search box

Tags: css, wordpress

I can't seem to change the style of the search box on my website. This is the website. Any help with a CSS code would be appreciated.
https://urbanyogalab.com/

Comment: Try with developer tools of your browser: https://nimb.ws/DniJkz

Answer (score 0):

These are elements that are your search box:
[image]

For example, if you want to remove borders for input field, you should do something like this:

```
.is-menu.is-dropdown form:not(.is-search-form) input[type=search] {
    border: none;
}
```

[image]

Similar to other elements you need changed.
Browser developer tools like Inspector are of great help in such situations.